# How can i check sql , and use something like do case

Tags: php, mysql, sql, categories, product

I am listing the categories and when clicking category it has to show if there is subcategory . If there isnt subcategory it includes products and have to list products.  I mean if includes product case b, else case a

I can use query a or b, But i dont know how to check if have products so use query a else use query b.

Sql :

```
Categories : id  |  parent_id  |  name
product to category : id | product_id | category_id
```

**query a (category list):**

```
<?php 
$query_product = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE status = '1' AND parent_id = '".$row['id']."' ORDER BY sort_order");
              while($row_product = mysql_fetch_array($query_product)){ 
                 $product_name = $row_product['name'];
               }
        ?>
```

**query b (product list):**

```
$query_product_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_to_category WHERE category_id = '".$row['id']."'");
                while($row_product_id = mysql_fetch_array($query_product_id)){
                //sort order yapilacak.
                $query_product = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = '1' AND id = '".$row_product_id['product_id']."' ORDER BY sort_order");
                  $row_product = mysql_fetch_array($query_product);

                    $product_name = $row_product['name'];
                   }
            ?>
```

Comment: So whats actually wrong here? you haven't actually asked a question

Comment: Not entirely sure what the problem is your facing? You could load in all categories and sub-categories and handle this client side to prevent yourself having to query the database every time a category has clicked.

Comment: Question is i dont know how to check the situation and do the right case. I cant list with query a but cant check products and do query b instead of query a

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not telling my question clearly.I found a solution like this but couldnt integrate. I can check if there are products.

I have to use a variable like **$code** includes

```
<div id="container-portfolio" class="portfolio-4">
               <?php 
              $query_product = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE status = '1' AND parent_id = '".$row['id']."' ORDER BY sort_order");
                 while($row_product = mysql_fetch_array($query_product)){ 
                  if($language != 'TR'){
                    $query_product_lang = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM categories WHERE language = '".$language."' AND language_parent_id = '".$row_product['id']."'");
                    $row_product_lang = mysql_fetch_array($query_product_lang);
                    $product_name = $row_product_lang['name'];
                   } else {
                    $product_name = $row_product['name'];
                   }
            ?>
```

**and $link**

```
<a href="<?php echo get('site_link'); ?>c/<?php echo $row_product['link']; ?>" >
                <img src="<?php echo HTTP_RESIM.'categories/'.$row_product['image']; ?>" alt="" /></a>
```

**Then use the if statement like below.** If you can help me for editing variables, i could use the others i think. Getting errors converting html to php for echo code.

**Regards**

```
<?php $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_to_category WHERE category_id = '".$row['id']."'");   

                $urun = mysql_num_rows($sql);
                if($urun > 0)  {

                $code= "......";
                $link= "....";  

                 } else {
                $code= "......";
                $link= "....";                   
                }   
            ?>
```